# Неправильная ссылка подставляется

Tags: html

Ставлю ссылку на фейсбук вида: =
впереди ссылки подставляется адрес моего сайта и потом ссылка =
на иконке фейсбука здесь

ссылка в диве:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU" class="stm-site-preloader" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/xmlrpc.php">
    <title>Bebko Consulting &#8212; Брокерская деятельность, оформление страхования, оформление кредитования, лизинговые соглашения</title>
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Bebko Consulting &raquo; Лента" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Bebko Consulting &raquo; Лента комментариев" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/comments/feed/" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.3\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.3\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/bebko-consulting.ks.ua\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.1"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a,b){var c=String.fromCharCode;l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,a),0,0);var d=k.toDataURL();l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,b),0,0);var e=k.toDataURL();return d===e}function e(a){var b;if(!l||!l.fillText)return!1;switch(l.textBaseline="top",l.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return!(b=d([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819]))&&(b=d([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]),!b);case"emoji":return b=d([55358,56794,8205,9794,65039],[55358,56794,8203,9794,65039]),!b}return!1}function f(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var g,h,i,j,k=b.createElement("canvas"),l=k.getContext&&k.getContext("2d");for(j=Array("flag","emoji"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},i=0;i<j.length;i++)c.supports[j[i]]=e(j[i]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[j[i]],"flag"!==j[i]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[j[i]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(h=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",h,!1),a.addEventListener("load",h,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",h),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),g=c.source||{},g.concatemoji?f(g.concatemoji):g.wpemoji&&g.twemoji&&(f(g.twemoji),f(g.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stm-stm-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/stm_fonts/stm/stm.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dwqa-style-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/dw-question-answer/templates/assets/css/style.css?ver=180720161352' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dwqa-rtl-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/dw-question-answer/templates/assets/css/rtl.css?ver=180720161352' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-plugin-settings-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/settings.css?ver=5.4.6.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='rs-plugin-settings-inline-css' type='text/css'>
#rs-demo-id {}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/themes/bebko/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=1.' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/themes/bebko/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='consulting-style-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/themes/bebko/style.css?ver=1.' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='consulting-layout-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/themes/bebko/assets/css/layout_1/main.css?ver=1.' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='consulting-layout-inline-css' type='text/css'>
.page_title{ background-repeat: repeat !important; }
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='select2-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/themes/bebko/assets/css/select2.min.css?ver=1.' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='consulting-default-font-css'  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A400%2C300%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%26subset%3Dlatin%2Cgreek%2Cgreek-ext%2Cvietnamese%2Ccyrillic-ext%2Clatin-ext%2Ccyrillic%7CPoppins%3A400%2C500%2C300%2C600%2C700%26subset%3Dlatin%2Clatin-ext%2Cdevanagari&#038;ver=1.' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stm_megamenu-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/themes/bebko/inc/megamenu/assets/css/megamenu.css?ver=4.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='js_composer_front-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css?ver=5.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='addtoany-css'  href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/addtoany.min.css?ver=1.14' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stm-google-fonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%7COpen+Sans%3Aregular%2Citalic%2C700%2C300%2C300italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic&#038;subset=cyrillic%2Cdevanagari%2Cvietnamese%2Cgreek-ext%2Clatin%2Ccyrillic-ext%2Cgreek%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=1.' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/addtoany.min.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.6.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.4.6.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/themes/bebko/inc/megamenu/assets/js/megamenu.js?ver=4.9.1'></script>
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.9.1" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbebko-consulting.ks.ua%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbebko-consulting.ks.ua%2F&#038;format=xml" />

<script type="text/javascript">
window.a2a_config=window.a2a_config||{};a2a_config.callbacks=[];a2a_config.overlays=[];a2a_config.templates={};a2a_localize = {
    Share: "Отправить",
    Save: "Сохранить",
    Subscribe: "Подписаться",
    Email: "Email",
    Bookmark: "В закладки!",
    ShowAll: "Показать все",
    ShowLess: "Показать остальное",
    FindServices: "Найти сервис(ы)",
    FindAnyServiceToAddTo: "Найти сервис и добавить",
    PoweredBy: "Работает на",
    ShareViaEmail: "Share via email",
    SubscribeViaEmail: "Subscribe via email",
    BookmarkInYourBrowser: "Добавить в закладки",
    BookmarkInstructions: "Press Ctrl+D or \u2318+D to bookmark this page",
    AddToYourFavorites: "Добавить в Избранное",
    SendFromWebOrProgram: "Send from any email address or email program",
    EmailProgram: "Email program",
    More: "More&#8230;"
};

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js" async="async"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = 'http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        </script>
        <meta name="generator" content="Powered by WPBakery Page Builder - drag and drop page builder for WordPress."/>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/vc_lte_ie9.min.css" media="screen"><![endif]--><style type="text/css">#wpadminbar ul li#wp-admin-bar-ucp-info { padding: 5px 0; } #wpadminbar ul li#wp-admin-bar-ucp-settings, #wpadminbar ul li#wp-admin-bar-ucp-status { } #wpadminbar i.ucp-status-dot { font-size: 17px; margin-top: -7px; color: #02ca02; height: 17px; display: inline-block; } #wpadminbar i.ucp-status-dot-enabled { color: #87c826; } #wpadminbar i.ucp-status-dot-disabled { color: #ea1919; } #wpadminbar #ucp-status-wrapper { display: inline; border: 1px solid rgba(240,245,250,.7); padding: 0; margin: 0 0 0 5px; background: rgb(35, 40, 45); } #wpadminbar .ucp-status-btn { padding: 0 7px; color: #fff; } #wpadminbar #ucp-status-wrapper.off #ucp-status-off { background: #ea1919;} #wpadminbar #ucp-status-wrapper.on #ucp-status-on { background: #66b317; }#wp-admin-bar-under-construction-page img.logo { height: 17px; margin-bottom: 4px; padding-right: 3px; } body.wp-admin #wp-admin-bar-under-construction-page img.logo { margin-bottom: -4px; }</style><style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
<meta name="generator" content="Powered by Slider Revolution 5.4.6.2 - responsive, Mobile-Friendly Slider Plugin for WordPress with comfortable drag and drop interface." />
<link rel="icon" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-cropped-ico-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-cropped-ico-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-cropped-ico-180x180.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-cropped-ico-270x270.png" />
<script type="text/javascript">function setREVStartSize(e){
                try{ var i=jQuery(window).width(),t=9999,r=0,n=0,l=0,f=0,s=0,h=0;                   
                    if(e.responsiveLevels&&(jQuery.each(e.responsiveLevels,function(e,f){f>i&&(t=r=f,l=e),i>f&&f>r&&(r=f,n=e)}),t>r&&(l=n)),f=e.gridheight[l]||e.gridheight[0]||e.gridheight,s=e.gridwidth[l]||e.gridwidth[0]||e.gridwidth,h=i/s,h=h>1?1:h,f=Math.round(h*f),"fullscreen"==e.sliderLayout){var u=(e.c.width(),jQuery(window).height());if(void 0!=e.fullScreenOffsetContainer){var c=e.fullScreenOffsetContainer.split(",");if (c) jQuery.each(c,function(e,i){u=jQuery(i).length>0?u-jQuery(i).outerHeight(!0):u}),e.fullScreenOffset.split("%").length>1&&void 0!=e.fullScreenOffset&&e.fullScreenOffset.length>0?u-=jQuery(window).height()*parseInt(e.fullScreenOffset,0)/100:void 0!=e.fullScreenOffset&&e.fullScreenOffset.length>0&&(u-=parseInt(e.fullScreenOffset,0))}f=u}else void 0!=e.minHeight&&f<e.minHeight&&(f=e.minHeight);e.c.closest(".rev_slider_wrapper").css({height:f})                  
                }catch(d){console.log("Failure at Presize of Slider:"+d)}
            };</script>
<style type="text/css" title="dynamic-css" class="options-output">h1, .h1,
                    h2, .h2,
                    h3, .h3,
                    h4, .h4,
                    h5, .h5,
                    h6, .h6,
                    .top_nav .top_nav_wrapper > ul,
                    .top_nav .icon_text strong,
                    .stm_testimonials .item .testimonial-info .testimonial-text .name,
                    .stats_counter .counter_title,
                    .stm_contact .stm_contact_info .stm_contact_job,
                    .vacancy_table_wr .vacancy_table thead th,
                    .testimonials_carousel .testimonial .info .position,
                    .testimonials_carousel .testimonial .info .company,
                    .stm_gmap_wrapper .gmap_addresses .addresses .item .title,
                    .company_history > ul > li .year,
                    .stm_contacts_widget,
                    .stm_works_wr.grid .stm_works .item .item_wr .title,
                    .stm_works_wr.grid_with_filter .stm_works .item .info .title,
                    body .vc_general.vc_btn3,
                    .consulting-rev-title,
                    .consulting-rev-title-2,
                    .consulting-rev-title-3,
                    .consulting-rev-text,
                    body .vc_tta-container .vc_tta.vc_general.vc_tta-tabs.theme_style .vc_tta-tabs-container .vc_tta-tabs-list .vc_tta-tab a,
                    strong, b,
                    .button,
                    .woocommerce a.button,
                    .woocommerce button.button,
                    .woocommerce input.button,
                    .woocommerce-cart .wc-proceed-to-checkout a.checkout-button,
                    .woocommerce input.button.alt,
                    .request_callback p,
                    ul.comment-list .comment .comment-author,
                    .page-numbers .page-numbers,
                    #footer .footer_widgets .widget.widget_recent_entries ul li a,
                    .default_widgets .widget.widget_nav_menu ul li,
                    .default_widgets .widget.widget_categories ul li,
                    .default_widgets .widget.widget_product_categories ul li,
                    .stm_sidebar .widget.widget_nav_menu ul li, .stm_sidebar .widget.widget_categories ul li,
                    .stm_sidebar .widget.widget_product_categories ul li,
                    .shop_widgets .widget.widget_nav_menu ul li,
                    .shop_widgets .widget.widget_categories ul li,
                    .shop_widgets .widget.widget_product_categories ul li,
                    .default_widgets .widget.widget_recent_entries ul li a,
                    .stm_sidebar .widget.widget_recent_entries ul li a,
                    .shop_widgets .widget.widget_recent_entries ul li a,
                    .staff_bottom_wr .staff_bottom .infos .info,
                    .woocommerce .widget_price_filter .price_slider_amount .button,
                    .woocommerce ul.product_list_widget li .product-title,
                    .woocommerce ul.products li.product .price,
                    .woocommerce a.added_to_cart,
                    .woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a,
                    .woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations label,
                    .woocommerce table.shop_table th,
                    .woocommerce-cart table.cart th.product-name a,
                    .woocommerce-cart table.cart td.product-name a,
                    .woocommerce-cart table.cart th .amount,
                    .woocommerce-cart table.cart td .amount,
                    .stm_services .item .item_wr .content .read_more,
                    .staff_list ul li .staff_info .staff_department,
                    .stm_partner.style_2 .stm_partner_content .position,
                    .staff_carousel_item .staff_department,
                    body.header_style_5 .header_top .info-text strong,
                    .stm_services_tabs .services_categories ul li a,
                    .stm_services_tabs .service_tab_item .service_name,
                    .stm_services_tabs .service_tab_item .service_cost,
                    .stm_works_wr.grid_2.style_1 .stm_works .item .item_wr .title,
                    .stm_works_wr.grid_2.style_2 .stm_works .item .item_wr .title,
                    .stm_works_wr.grid_with_filter.style_1 .stm_works .item .item_wr .title,
                    .stm_works_wr.grid_with_filter.style_2 .stm_works .item .item_wr .title,
                    body.header_style_7 .side_nav .main_menu_nav > li > a,
                    body.header_style_7 .side_nav .main_menu_nav > li ul li a,
                    body.header_style_5 .header_top .info-text b{font-family:Open Sans;}h1, .h1{text-transform:lowercase;}h2, .h2{text-transform:lowercase;}</style>
<style type="text/css" data-type="vc_shortcodes-custom-css">.vc_custom_1450677977665{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}.vc_custom_1450692516354{margin-bottom: 60px !important;}.vc_custom_1450856873482{margin-bottom: 37px !important;}.vc_custom_1451476985704{padding-top: 53px !important;padding-bottom: 70px !important;background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;}.vc_custom_1511854933343{margin-bottom: 42px !important;padding-top: 66px !important;padding-bottom: 66px !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}.vc_custom_1453109987955{margin-bottom: -60px !important;padding-top: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;}.vc_custom_1513063577086{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}.vc_custom_1513168205722{margin-bottom: 28px !important;}</style><noscript><style type="text/css"> .wpb_animate_when_almost_visible { opacity: 1; }</style></noscript></head>
<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-1024 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support site_layout_1  header_style_1 sticky_menu header_transparent wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-5.4.2 vc_responsive">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="fullpage" class="content_wrapper">
<header id="header">
                <div class="header_top clearfix">
            <div class="container">
                                    <div class="header_socials">
                                                    <a target="_blank" href="facebook.com/BebkoConsulting​"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/bebko_consulting/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                            <a href="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/"><img src="http://bebko-consulting.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/bg.png" style="width: px; height: px;" alt="Bebko Consulting" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                                                                <div class="icon_text clearfix">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                            <div class="text">
                                Пн-Пт 9:00-18:00<br>
Сб 9:00-16:00<br>
Вс выходной<br>                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                                <div class="icon_text clearfix">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa fa-map-marker"></i></div>
                            <div class="text stm_st_address_1">
                                Бериславське шосе, 11,<br>Николаевское шоссе,4 км                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top_nav">
```

Comment: код покажите, как именно Вы ставите ссылку

Comment: `https://facebook.com/...`

Comment: http:// перед facebook добавьте и перед инстаграм

Comment: добавил все равно, главное инстаграм нормальная ссылка а фейсбук нет, код идентичный       <div class="header_socials">
                                                    <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/BebkoConsulting;"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.instagram.com/bebko_consulting/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                                            </div>

Comment: точку с запятой после адреса уберите

Comment: убрал, не помогло, может быть в css что то зарыто?

Comment: css вряд ли влияет - где-то у вас косяк чисто синтаксический. напишите код в самом вопросе, чтобы можно было посмотреть, как ссылки открываются (в комментариях код отображается некорректно)

Comment: добавил код, его можно в живую посмотреть на bebko-consulting.ks.ua поиском header_socials div будет

Comment: ну так и нет у Вас перед facebook https://

Comment: поставил только что, но это не помогает, главное инстаграм нормально отображается а фб нет, фантомный баг какойто

Comment: скопировал Вашу ссылку в jsfiddle - там после адреса какой-то невидимый символ ещё добавляется. Вы из word'а, что ли, переносили? удалите адрес и пропишите его заново нормально, без копипаста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы перейти на *отдельный сайт*, а не на его *страницу*, необходимо указать http:// или https://. Иначе Вы попадете на страницу сайта, где стоит ссылка.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так всё работает:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com/BebkoConsulting">FB</a>
```

Comment: тут работает, а на сайте нет(

Comment: Вы мою ссылку скопировали? Если нет, то скопируйте и вставьте вместо Вашей

Comment: спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @AlexanderSpiridonov Пожалуйста, не забудьте принять ответ, щелкнув на значок "галочка" слева от ответа.